# How to embed a custom font in my application

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to add a custom font to my application, and I have already added to my resource file.

[image]

And my code as the following:

```
int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/ae_AlMateen.ttf");
QMessageBox::information(this,"Message",QString::number(id));
```

---

Also the content of `.qrc` file.

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/fonts">
        <file alias="ae_AlMateen">ae_AlMateen.ttf</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

But the problem is that the `addApplicationFont` always returns `-1`.

**Note that** when change the `:/fonts/ae_AlMateen.ttf` to direct path ex:`C://ae_AlMateen.ttf` it works fine.

I want the font file to be integrated with my application executable file, in order to make the application does not need to attach the font file with it.

Comment: The code is correct and works. The bug is not in the part you are showing us. You can create a QDir(":/fonts") and see whats in this virtual folder. Or your ttf is corrupt.

Comment: @Greenflow: Thanks, about this part "Or your ttf is corrupt." I have been updated a portion in my question. As for the `QDir(":/fonts")` I don't understand what do I do with it.

Comment: ":/fonts" is a virtual filesystem. You can create a QDir object with it like with any other folder. Then you can look what your program actually sees in this folder, e.g. with QDir::entryList. But as I see it now, your build does not find your *.ttf. Unless your source tree is directly in c:

Comment: @Greenflow: I have checked the `QDir(":/fonts")` as you said, and gave me the font file name from inside the virtual filesystem like that `ae_AlMateen` without its extension. also please review my question I have been updated it (bottom part).

Comment: Sounds wrong. The font should appear with extension. Not much I can help. This code works perfectly for me. QDir::entryList shows the full name of the font. And QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont returns 0.

Comment: Could post the content of your .qrc file? Not that I expect to see anything. Your problem is strange.

Comment: And try a deperate hack: When the font is without '.ttf' in your resources, try to load it without: int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/ae_AlMateen");

Comment: For a minute I was thinking, if this could have something to do with Window's 'feature' to hide known extensions... but this would be stupid.

Comment: @Greenflow: That's it, finally the problem has been solved. the reason was add the font name with its extension, the following is wrong `(":/fonts/ae_AlMateen.ttf")`. when remove the font extension as you said, the problem solved, the correct is `(":/fonts/ae_AlMateen")`. Thank you for continued help me.

Comment: Great that it worked... I just have not the slightest idea why. I mean why the extension was swallowed. Dismissing it as a 'Windows thing' is dangerous, since it breaks platform independence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhh... now, after you added your .qrc, I understand. Easy to explain:

```
<file alias="ae_AlMateen">ae_AlMateen.ttf</file>
```

You added an alias in your .qrc file. If you remove **alias="ae_AlMateen"** it will work as we all expected... with .ttf extension.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using qml also, you can load font in qml file [in this way](http://kdeblog.mageprojects.com/2012/11/20/using-fonts-awesome-in-qml). I recommend it.

And if you still want to load font from cpp file, please read [this article](http://blog.binaryking.in/post/79670882780/using-font-awesome-in-your-qt-app), it may help you.

**Edit**:
The following code can work on Qt5.4.1 on OSX10.10. (The font is embedded in executable file)

```
int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
QMessageBox::information(NULL,"Message",QString::number(id));  // this shows id is 0.

QFont font;
font.setFamily("FontAwesome");
font.setPointSize(30);
ui->commandLinkButton->setFont(font);
ui->commandLinkButton->setText("\uf021"); // this shows the Refresh icon.
```

**Edit2**: 
I made another test on Win7 with Qt5.4.1(msvc2013 64bit). The font is embedded in the exe file. Everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks, I don't use `Qml`, and I have seen that article before and it did not help me.

Comment: Thanks, but that code works if the application works in the same machine that has the font file. but I want the font file to be integrated with my application executable file.

Comment: Yeah! The font is embedded in the exe file. And it works fine with Qt5.4.1 on Win7 also. I just tested it.